# Regex to find DIV tags and retrieve image name

Tags: html, regex, wordpress

I have to replace several thousands links to images hosted on Photobucket, and change the links to a different hosting site. The links are contained in posts in a Wordpress site. Namely, I have to find the following syntax:

```
<div style="clear: both; text-align: center;"><a href="http://photobucket.com/albums/mypath/IMAGENAME.jpg" style="margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" src="photobucket.com/albums/mypath/IMAGENAME.jpg" /></a></div>
```

where `mypath` can vary, and replace the entire `DIV` tag with

```
<img class="alignnone size-full aligncenter" src="http://mynewpath/IMAGENAME.jpg" alt="" />
```

I found the [Search Regex plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-regex/) for WordPress, which allows mass Search & Replace using RegEx's. Unfortunately I can't create a RegEx specific enough to identify only the `DIV` tags that I want. I came up with this:

```
<div\b[^>]*>.*?<img.*?photobucket.*?\/(.*?\.jpg).*?<\/div>
```

which works most of the times. However, it sometimes captures consecutive pairs of `DIV` tags. How can I be sure to capture a single `DIV` tag and capture the image name inside?

PS: I know that parsing HTML with RegEx's is not recommended, but the Search Regex plugin is the quickest way I found to solve my problem.

EDIT: edited the example for clarity

Comment: Why wouldn't you do SQL search and replace? You could change data itself rather then overwritting it on the front end with some script...

Comment: @TomislavSvecak uhm... that might be an option, but the WordPress site is hosted, and I'm not sure how to access the database directly. I'm just trying to help a friend out, and I thought that a Regex would be the quickest way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use jQuery to do that for you.
Since you don't have access to SQL to search and replace.

lets say you have URL like this http://replaceThis.com/somethingSomething
WIth next jQuery you could replace all instances of that url:

```
$('a[href^="http://replaceThis.com"]').each(function(){
  var thisHref = $(this).attr('href');
  thisHref.replace('replaceThis','withThis');
});
```

EDIT:

You could use http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/ 
You can check if this element has parent div and if it does unwrap it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately I have to change the DIV tag as well, not just the URL. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: Ahh sorry haven't seen that one. What do you need to change in that DIV tag?

Comment: I have to replace the entire DIV tag with just the IMG tag. See my example in the original question, edited for clarity (I hope :))